# Get count of relationship rows between three tables that are not duplicates

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a (local) MySQL database, which is a *Drupal 6* export. It has these relevant tables:

1. `node` - Contains *articles*, plus also information about their *department* and *section*s. I'm interested in `nid` and `title` columns.
2. `content_field_department` - Has the relationships between *article nodes* and *department nodes*. I'm interested in `nid` (the *article node*) and `field_department_nid` (the *department node*) columns.
3. `content_field_section` - Has the relationships between *article nodes* and *section nodes*. I'm interested in `nid` (the *article node*) and `field_section_nid` (the *section node*) columns.

I'm trying to get an accurate COUNT for how many times a given *article node* is related to each *section* or *department node* (performance is not relevant for me at this time, since it's local and it can take as long as it needs to without causing problems). That is, I'd like data like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Section Name    | Count of Articles |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Department Name | Count of Articles |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

**The issue**

One problem is when the interface was originally built, a *department choice* for an *article* also included all of the *sections*. A *section choice*, though, never included the *departments*. So in cases where an *article node* is related to another *node* twice, both as a *section* and as a *department*, I would like to COUNT that only once.

**My current try**

My current attempt is like this:

- To get a *department* COUNT:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT d.field_department_nid as tid, n.title as name, (
          SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nid, field_department_nid)
          FROM content_field_department d2
          WHERE d2.field_department_nid = d.field_department_nid
          AND nid NOT IN (
              SELECT s.nid from content_field_section s
              LEFT OUTER JOIN node n2 ON s.nid = n2.nid
              WHERE field_section_nid IS NOT NULL
          )
      ) as drupal_department_count
  FROM content_field_department d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node n ON d.field_department_nid = n.nid
  ORDER BY drupal_department_count DESC
  ```
- To get a *section* COUNT:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT s.field_section_nid as tid, n.title as name, (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nid, field_section_nid)
          FROM content_field_section s2
          WHERE s2.field_section_nid = s.field_section_nid
          AND nid NOT IN (
              SELECT d.nid from content_field_department d
              LEFT OUTER JOIN node n2 ON d.nid = n2.nid
              WHERE field_department_nid IS NOT NULL
          )
      ) as drupal_section_count
  FROM content_field_section s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN node n ON s.field_section_nid = n.nid
  ORDER BY drupal_section_count DESC
  ```

I had also tried without the `NOT IN` additions, but the COUNT is *too high*, I think because the same *node combination* can be COUNTed in both tables.

What direction do I need to go with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your "issue"?  Are you saying that each article should only link to one department OR one section (if the data were ideal)?

Comment: @ArinTaylor well, it's just that an article node can potentially link to another node twice. I don't need to change that or anything; it just makes it hard to count how many articles are in a section or department, when a single node can appear as both a section and a department, and be linked to an article as both. Does that clarify any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more information about your business restrictions to write an ideal query, but here's my advice given my interpretation of what you've said so far.

First thing you need to do is more clearly define what you are trying to achieve.

> So in cases where an article node is related to another node twice, both as a section and as a department, I would like to COUNT that only once.

Since your final result set will be grouped by departments and sections, "counting it only once" means you need to pick where they should be counted.  For example:

```
   content_field_department         content_field_section
+-----+----------------------+   +-----+-------------------+
| nid | field_department_nid |   | nid | field_section_nid |
+-----+----------------------+   +-----+-------------------+
|  1  |          2           |   |  1  |         3         |
+-----+----------------------+   +-----+-------------------+
```

should `nid` 1 be counted in the list for department `nid` 2 or counted for section `nid` 3?  Based on your question, you may want to only count it for departments.  In your current query drafts, you are trying to exclude the issue case from both counts, meaning you are effectively counting it 0 times instead of 1 (your goal) or 2 (what you are trying to avoid).

Here's a draft query as a starting point:

```
select
    DeptOrSect,
    nid,
    title,
    count(1)
from (
    select
        'DEPT' as DeptOrSect,
        dept.nid,
        dept.title,
        link.nid as article_nid
    from node dept
    join content_field_department link on link.field_department_nid = dept.nid
    union all
    select
        'SECT' as DeptOrSect,
        sect.nid,
        sect.title,
        link.nid as article_nid
    from node sect
    join content_field_section link on link.field_section_nid = sect.nid
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from content_field_department dept
        where dept.nid = link.nid
    )
) as x
group by DeptOrSect,
    nid,
    title;
```

Comment: This seems to give me exactly what I need. Many thanks.